# Find non-unique values in a db with criteria present

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I am using a SQLite Server and I don't understand how to achieve my goal.

I have a database called `billing` that looks like:

```
+------------+---------+-------+---------+--------+
|         ID | Account | Date  | Product | Charge |
+------------+---------+-------+---------+--------+
|          1 |       1 | 04-01 | Water   |  20    |
|          1 |       1 | 04-02 | Water   |  20    |
|          2 |       2 | 06-01 | Phone   |  30    |
|          2 |       3 | 08-04 | Water   |  40    |
+------------+---------+-------+---------+--------+
```

I am trying to find the sum of all the most recent charges for all the products combined. Meaning, I would have to sum together $20 for ID-1 (the one dated 04-01 is ignored because its not most recent) for their water bill, and $30 and $40 for ID-2's Water and Phone bills.

Right now, I'm using Python's `sqlite3` module and am using:

```
for i in range (2):
    c.execute("SELECT Charge FROM billing WHERE ID = " + str(i+1) + " ORDER BY Date DESC")
    rows = c.fetchone()
    sum.x += rows[0]
print("Todays Sum = $" + str(sum.x))
```

But using this method makes only one value from ID-2 to be counted. The least recent one is not counted because the database is being descended.

How can I apply the criteria that the ID has to be unique, while also looking for non-unique Products?

Comment: Are your dates stored in `YY-MM` format or `MM-YY` format?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen MM-DD. My bad about the MySQL, i changed it.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)).  By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plese change the query to below and try again:

```
SELECT sum(Charge) FROM billing WHERE ID = " + str(i+1) + " group by id ORDER BY Date DESC
```

Comment: Well, If I do that, them everything is summed. Including both of ID-1's  $20 charges, where instead only one is wanted.

Comment: you are passing ID is argument if ID is 2 it will never include those/

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
SELECT SUM(b1.Charge)
FROM billing b1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Account, Product, MAX(Date) AS max_date
    FROM billing
    GROUP BY Account, Product
) b2
    ON b1.Account = b2.Account AND
       b1.Product = b2.Product AND
       b1.Date = b2.max_date;
```

A critical assumption here is that your dates are stored in `YY-MM` format.  If you stored them as `MM-YY`, then they won't sort properly and you have an even bigger problem with your table.